# Configure schema and utterances programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-voice-service, alexa-skills-kit

Whenever a I change my alexa skill in a way that the utterenaces or schema are modified I have to manually enter to the amazon developer console and change utterances or schema manually in the textbox.

I 've already automated the process of uploading a new version of the .zip containing the aws lambda function and I would really like to be able to automate the update of utterances and schema.

Comment: How did you automate the zip upload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very frequent feedback we do receive from developers, but this is not possible to automate that part, as of today (April 11 2016).

Comment: Is there any progress on this 4 month after?

Comment: We know this is important for our customers, but I can not share an ETA for the moment.

Comment: Finally Skill API is here. https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/e7a57ec4-f9e0-4efa-9052-06d320245f9b/announcing-alexa-skill-management-api-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface-and-events-in-alexa-skills-kit